# "dir" parameter in Shell.Execute command doesn't work when "verb" parameter contains "runas" option

Tags: vbscript

The current directory remains "C:\Windows\System32" despite I pass my current directory to the "dir" parameter.

```
If CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("%ComSpec% /C ""NET FILE""", 0, True) <> 0 Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory, "runas", 5
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

How can I solve the problem?

My answer:

I have solved with:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 0 Then WScript.Quit 1
RunAsAdmin
Main

Sub RunAsAdmin()
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set Env = Shell.Environment("VOLATILE")
    If Shell.Run("%ComSpec% /C ""NET FILE""", 0, True) <> 0 Then
        Env("CurrentDirectory") = Shell.CurrentDirectory
        ArgsList = ""
        For i = 1 To WScript.Arguments.Count
            ArgsList = ArgsList & """ """ & WScript.Arguments(i - 1)
        Next
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & ArgsList & """", , "runas", 5
        WScript.Quit
    End If
    Shell.CurrentDirectory = Env("CurrentDirectory")
    Env.Remove("CurrentDirectory")
End Sub

Sub Main()

End Sub
```

Comment: I checked the duplicate topic and even though I saw that it contains the solution to my problem, it is difficult to understand. I would like an answer on my topic because it contains the simple case.

Comment: The answer would be the same I already posted in response to the other question.

Comment: What about something like `auxvar =  CreateObject( "WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory` and then  pass the `auxvar` variable value as `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", auxvar, "runas", 5`

Comment: @JosefZ Why would that change anything? The problem is caused by the fact that elevation ignores the working directory for reasons Raymond Chen explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=24223).

Comment: JosefZ Nothing change.

Comment: My thought  was that you can pass a scalar value to the elevated script. Sorry if it's wrong [grin]…

Comment: I have understand now. The illustrated solution are or pass CD as argument (I do not like) or a second workaround solution not applicable for my case. I would like a more elegant solution.

Comment: And I would like my face on the one Dollar bills. Looks like we're both out of luck.

Comment: XD XD  I have found the solution.

Comment: FTR, if for some reason you think that using the volatile environment for passing the working directory is somehow a more elegant approach than using an additional argument: it's not.